# UI goes not responding in JavaFx

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, javafx, parallel-processing

We have application which is Integrated with Network device for performance and tuning related functionalities.

We are using JavaFx For UI, when ever i connect to Network device,for login and get responses the UI Show "Not Responding".

could any one suggest how to over come the issue.[Login screen shows not respongding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXPEt.png)

Answer (score 1):

The UI goes not responding because the program is connecting to the network device and the UI is being run in the same `Thread`. You need to start a new `Thread` to connect network device. When UI and connection to network device are in two different threads, the UI will not freeze.

```
class YourThread extends Thread{  
    public void run(){  
        // Your code to connect to network device
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        YourThread thread = new YourThread();   
        thread.start();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Yes, i understand but we have have multiple command sending to Network Device in multiple ways which i can't put in a *Thread*, can you suggest workaround in UI component..?

Comment: You can create a popup window (a new JavaFX`Scene`) that shows your user that your application is now handling the login. You may implement a progressbar. Then you put all the connection code into that `Scene`. When the connection is completed, that `Scene` disappears.

Comment: @user2964628 "we have have multiple command sending to Network Device in multiple ways which i can't put in a Thread". Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Any I/O done over a slow and unstable channel such as (but not limited to) a network is bound to give not responding user interfaces. Therefore any significant I/O should be done in a separate thread.

Some of the options you have are:

- Start a new thread
- Create a JavaFX [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) or [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html), provides easiest integration in user feedback and task progress feedback
- Use java 8's [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), or a chain of these
- Use reactive programming (which is CompletableFuture more or less)

See also: [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)