# JavaFX : When pinging an IP Address, the UI stucks for few seconds

Tags: javafx, ping, java-threads

Im working on Javafx, and i have set a program like if click PING button, a request is sent and returns connection status as true or false. And When i click button, the application hangs for few seconds and resumes work. But that delay is not accepted right. So i wanted to push this ping request operation to be performed in background. Any idea how to work?

```
public static Boolean sendPingRequest(String ipAddress) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{
    InetAddress geek = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    if (geek.isReachable(5000)) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mVue.png)

Comment: [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Comment: make your web calls on the different thread (not main thread)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UI goes not responding in JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867073/ui-goes-not-responding-in-javafx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Tasks. If you perform a lengthy operation on a button click, you block the JavaFX UI Thread.
Take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm